# Need help for vector embedding search with Open Ai embeddding and elastic search cosine similarity

Tags: elasticsearch, openai-api, openaiembeddings

Overview: I am creating a search engine using the Open Ai embeddings .I am using the dividing the documents in chunks and then converting the chunks to embedding and storing in Elastic Search(7.10).Now when i am sending a prompt i again convert to the same and do a script base cosine similarity search.
here is an example of elastic search query.

```
{
                    "script_score": {
                        "script": {
                            "source": "doc['associated_questions_vector_field'].size() == 0 ? 0 : (1  + cosineSimilarity(params.prompt_vector, doc['associated_questions_vector_field']) + (1 + cosineSimilarity(params.prompt_vector, doc['vector_field']))) / 2,
                            "params": {
                                "prompt_vector": query_vector
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Problem : Earlier it seemed to be working fine but now as the documents have increased i am getting wrong documents results any idea why that is happening and has anyone faced similar issue.

I was expeceting accurate results and a higher accuracy

Answer (score 1):

This approach is highly inefficient especially if you are planning to use that not only for scoring but also for search. Take a look at kNN search that provides the functionality you need only without scripting and with fast approximation of results on large data sets https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/knn-search.html

Comment: Thanks @imatov ,but i am currently using an elastic search 7.10 which doesn't have the feature mentioned by you,Is there any other thing that you can suggest to approach this problem.

Comment: 7.10 is more than 3 year old version that is no longer supported and is not getting security updates for more than 1.5 years. You should upgrade to something more recent and supported, especially if you are doing new development.